# Spring batch: use before- and after-step methods within a CompositeItemWriter

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I need to read data from db and then generate an XLSX file and update data in db.

No issue for the reader part.
For the writer part, I ended up creating a `CompositeItemWriter`, composed of a first `Writer` that generates the XLSX file and a second one that update data in db.

The problem: I need to intercept before- and after-step for the first writer in order to be able to properly write to the XLSX file in chunks. But, as soon as I compose both writers into a `CompositeItemWriter`, methods annotated with `@BeforeStep` et `@AfterStep` are not called.

Same issue when making the first writer implement `StepExecutionListener`.

Any idea why?

Here follows the CompositeItemWriter definition, the step and the writer:

```
public CompositeItemWriter<Adhesion> compositeItemWriter() {
  CompositeItemWriter writer = new CompositeItemWriter();
  writer.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(adhesionToXlsWriter,  adhesionToDbWriter));
  return writer;
}

@Bean
public Step xlsStep(ItemReader<Adhesion> adhesionFromDbReader) {
   return stepBuilderFactory.get(JOB_NAME + "-step")
      .<Adhesion, Adhesion>chunk(10)
      .reader(adhesionFromDbReader)
      .writer(compositeWriter())
      .build();
   }


@Component
public class AdhesionToXlsWriter implements ItemWriter<Adhesion> {

   @BeforeStep
   public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
      // !! never called !!
   }

   @Override
   public void write(List<? extends Adhesion> items) throws Exception {
      // generate XLSX content
   }

   @AfterStep
   public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
      // !! never called !!
   }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to register the XslWriter as listener to the step. Use the "listener" method of the stepBuilder.

If a writer, reader, processor is "hidden" behind a composite class, the spring framework will not recognize it as listener automatically. therefore you have to do  it "manually".

Comment: I can't remember. I'm almost sure, that this is described somewhere, I'm also almost sure that similar questions have already been asked here.

Comment: Here is the link to the reference that mentions it: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/htmlsingle/#delegatePatternAndRegistering. But in my opinion, it lacks of clarity :-). Anyway, thx!