# Spring Batch : CompositeItemWriter, @BeforeStep and Controlling StepExecution

Tags: spring-batch

I've stumbled upon a pretty twisted issue with a spring batch recently.
Requirements are as follows :

I have two main steps :

- The first one reads some data from an oracle database, from a table to write to another table.
- The second one does some other database stuff, based upon a data handled on first step.

From a design standpoint, first step looks like this :

```java
    @Bean
    public Step myFirstStep(JdbcCursorItemReader<Revision> reader) {

        return stepBuilderFactory.get("my-first-step")
            .<Revision, Revision>chunk(1)
            .reader(readerRevisionNumber)
            .writer(compositeItemWriter())
            .listener(executionContextPromotionListener())
            .build();
```

Composite item writer :

```java
    @Bean
    public CompositeItemWriter<Revision> compositeItemWriter() {
        CompositeItemWriter writer = new CompositeItemWriter();
        writer.setDelegates(Arrays.asList(somewriter(), someOtherwriter(), aWriterThatIsSupposedToPassDataToAnotherStep()));
        return writer;
    }
```

While the first two writer are not complex, my interest is focused on the third one.

```java
aWriterThatIsSupposedToPassDataToAnotherStep()
```

As you might have guessed, this one will be used to get some data being processed before, to promote it on my second Step :

```java
@Component
@StepScope
public class AWriterThatIsSupposedToPassDataToAnotherStep implements ItemWriter<SomeEntity> {

    private StepExecution stepExecution;

    public void write(List<? extends SomeEntity> items) {

        ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
        stepContext.put("revisionNumber", items.stream().findFirst().get().getSomeField());
        System.out.println("writing : " + items.stream().findFirst().get().getSomeField()+ "to ExecutionContext");
    }

    @BeforeStep
    public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
        this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    }

}
```

Problem is : As long as this writer is part of a composite writer list (as declared above)
The @BeforeStep of my last writer is never executed, this ends up me unable to transmit my information to execution context.
When replacing my CompositeItemWriter by my single "AWriterThatIsSupposedToPassDataToAnotherStep" inside step definition, it gets executed properly.

Does it have to do anything with some kind of declaration order or something ?

Big Thanks to further help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution (with some of my coworkers help), and sourced-in from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39698653/1957764

You'll need to both declare the writer as part of the composite writer AND a step listener to make it execute the @BeforeStep annotated method.